# Can not get inserted primary key at JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server in my project and I am using JDBC as connector. My project runs within Tomcat Server. What I am trying to do is gettiing primary key of a newly inserted value without writing one more select statement.

Here is my java code:

```
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(FIRSTNAME,STATUS)VALUES " +
                            "(?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    ps.setString(1, "name");
                    ps.setInt(2, status);
                    int updatedRows = ps.executeUpdate();
                    if(updatedRows > 0){
                        ResultSet resultSet = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                        if (resultSet.next()) {
                            // do some stuff with resultSet.getInt(1)
                            // but code does not enter here
                        }
                    }
```

But code does not enter the inner if clause statement as I mentioned in my comment. I also tried this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(FIRSTNAME,STATUS)VALUES " +
                            "(?,?)", new String[]{"USERID"});
```

Here USERID is name of the primary key of Users table. Both method did not worked. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the definition of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO Users(FIRSTNAME,STATUS) OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES (?,?)
```